# Recuperar campo específico de uma chave primária via get()

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3

Estou enfrentando um problema na hora de recuperar um campo específico da chave primária do meu banco de dados via `get()`. Tenho uma chave primária com dois campos: ('Id', 'IdContrato'), porém, eu não encontrei uma maneira de definir qual campo da minha primary key eu desejo obter:

```
$aditivo = $this->Aditivos->get($id);
```

O que eu precisaria no caso seria:

```
 $aditivo = $this->Aditivos->get($idcontrato);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se a chave primária é composta, você precisa passar ambas para obter a entidade via get:

```
$aditivo = $this->Aditivos->get([$id, $idcontrato]);
```